# How to programmatically remove a donut hole from Polygon in arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects

[image: Polygon with a hole in it]

I have a polygon `IPolygon4` with a hole in it, as you can see.  How can I get rid of the donut hole, and have the whole thing be one simple polygon with 5 vertices.

Here are the constructed WKT points, I projected to GCS_WGS_1984 so it would be more readable.

> MULTIPOLYGON (((-93.948870475981934 46.388792874272333,
>   -94.07064721379696 46.3298500944495, -94.292075670722767 46.511771884217374, -94.285856486919386 46.334338634913607, -94.043790864983947 46.2678965446348, -93.96530675201366 46.327504695188082, -93.948870475981934 46.388792874272333)), ((-93.948870475981934 46.388792874272333, -93.914198248635017
>   46.517621156043539, -94.292075670722767 46.511771884217374, -93.948870475981934 46.388792874272333)))

Comment: That's not really a donut hole, it's a non-[simple polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon). If you [simplify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003w0000000) it, I suspect that "hole" will go away.

Comment: @blah238 I called simplify on it, and that didn't fix it.

Comment: Could you post its [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)?

Comment: @blah238 I posted the points.

Comment: Have you seen this post, http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=131776?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the polygon is simple, and the hole is an interior ring, you can create a new polygon using the `IPolygon4.ExteriorRingBag` property, and replace the current geometry with the exterior ring (or rings in case of `MultiPolygon`).

Otherwise, if the polygon is a "spaghetti-polygon", where the holes is caused by exterior ring is messed up (no interior ring), you probably have to do a manual edit (e.g. using sketch properties).

EDIT: (After you updated your question with WKT)
The problem is that the geometry is NOT a donut polygon, it is a multipolygon. Therefore, you get two exterior rings in ExteriorRingBag instead of one. If the user wants to construct a polygon with a hole in ArcGis, the "Cut Polygon" tool must be used.

Here is a screenshot showing both polygon rings in your geometry:

[image]

Assuming that you are using ArcGis, here is the way to construct a donut properly:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000003q000000.htm

Comment: ExteriorRingBag gives me a top polygon and a bottom polygon.  I can't do it manually because the use case is that the user will construct the polygon.

Comment: Your WKT shows the problem, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
    IPolygon ppolygon = pFeature.ShapeCopy as IPolygon;
    IGeometryCollection pgeomColl = ppolygon as IGeometryCollection;
    int x = pgeomColl.GeometryCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    { 
       IGeometry pNewGeom = pgeomColl.get_Geometry(i);
       IFeatureBuffer featureBuffer = pFeatureClass.CreateFeatureBuffer();
       for (int k = 0; k <= pFeatureClass.Fields.FieldCount - 1; k++)
        {
        if (pFeatureClass.Fields.get_Field(k).Editable &&   pFeatureClass.Fields.get_Field(k).Type != esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry)
 {
  featureBuffer.set_Value(k, pFeature.get_Value(k));
   }
  }

  IGeometryCollection icollection = null;
  if (pFeature.Shape.GeometryType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline)
      icollection = new PolylineClass();
  else if (pFeature.Shape.GeometryType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
      icollection = new PolygonClass();

   icollection.AddGeometry(pNewGeom, ref miss, ref miss);

   IGeometry pgeomNew = (IGeometry)icollection;
   IZAware pZ1 = pFeature.Shape as IZAware;
   if (pZ1.ZAware)
   {
    pZ1 = pgeomNew as IZAware;
    pZ1.ZAware = true;
    }
   else
   {
    pZ1 = pgeomNew as IZAware;
    pZ1.ZAware = false;
    }
   featureBuffer.Shape = pgeomNew;
                                                  insertFeatureCursor.InsertFeature(featureBuffer);
  marshal_object(featureBuffer);
  marshal_object(pgeomNew);
 marshal_object(pNewGeom);
marshal_object(icollection);
insertFeatureCursor.Flush();
}
pFeature.Delete();
 marshal_object(ppolygon);
```

Comment: I think this Answer could do with you using the edit button to apply more formatting and also some descriptive text about how your code answers the Question.